# Django post save function not saving

Tags: django

I have post save function that I am trying to execute to update the count on my model.

I have tried these two methods of doing the post save, they are all not updating my counter to "5" inside my database after I do a save on my admin page.

```
# method for updating
def update_tagpoll(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    # countptype = c.polltype.count()
    # TagPoll.objects.count = countptype
    instance.counter = 5

post_save.connect(update_tagpoll, sender=TagPoll)


# method for updating
@receiver(post_save, sender=TagPoll, dispatch_uid="update_tagpoll_count")
def update_tagpoll(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     instance.counter == 5
```

I also tried to do a instance.save()which would lead to a maximum recursion issue(which is expected)

below is the model that I am trying to update.

```
class TagPoll(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    polltype = models.ManyToManyField(Ptype, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    counter = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

I cant seem to find what the issue, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `instance.counter == 5` does not set `instance.counter` to 5 - it checks to see if it equals 5. Also if you're modifying the model, you'll probably need to do that in the `pre_save` hook, as it's too late by the time you get the `post_save` one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In signals you trying to check if the `instance.counter` is 5. You have to add it by 5 or change to 5.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=TagPoll, dispatch_uid="update_tagpoll_count")
def update_tagpoll(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     instance.counter = 5
     # instance.counter += 5 if you want to increment it by 5.
     instance.save()
```

`post_save` would result in recursion, hence you should use `pre_save` signal IMO.

Which would modify the value of counter just before saving the instance.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=TagPoll, dispatch_uid="update_tagpoll_count")
def update_tagpoll(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     instance.counter = 5
     # instance.counter += 5 if you want to increment it by 5.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=TagPoll)
def update_tagpoll(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     instance.counter = 5
```